# One field of a table, exclusive to another in Django Tables

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models here, related to each other. What I am trying to do here is to avoid repetition. For example in grade 9, their can only be one rollno = 32 (cannot have two) but two same roll numbers in different grades are possible.

Example: name= Mark, grade=9, rollno = 32 and name = Shub, grade = 9, rollno = 32 shouldn't be possible but name= Mark, grade=9, rollno = 32 and name= Mark, grade=10, rollno = 32 should be possible.

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    grade = models.ForeignKey(grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rollno = models.BigIntegerField()
```

I am not quite sure how to add this functionality.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a meta class to your model.

Your student model would look something like this:

```
    class Student(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            unique_together = ("grade", "rollno")

        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        grade = models.ForeignKey(grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        rollno = models.BigIntegerField()
```

The documentation on meta options for django models are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together

They're really useful.

As a side note, it's convention to use underscores and full words in variable names. You should consider changing `rollno` to `roll_number`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `unique_together` in class meta.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("grade", "rollno")
```

Details documentation available [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together)